# Setting the Parent on a CustomTaskPane control?

Tags: c#, forms, plugins, parent, customtaskpane

I'm creating a CustomTaskPane for a Word plugin, and putting some third party controls on the control that's on the CustomTaskPane.  However, those controls are expecting to be part of a .net Form, and call FindForm() on themselves, which traverses the Control.Parent tree up until it hits a Form.

However, the CustomTaskPane control never gets a parent, and isn't on a .Net form.  I'm using the same code I've seen on Microsoft's website and elsewhere to add my CustomTaskPane (C#):

MyControl ctrl = new MyControl;
Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(ctrl, "Custom Pane");

At this point, ctrl.Parent is null.... and I can't find a valid control to set as the parent.  I'm running as a plugin, so I don't have a reference to a form, all the objects available are COM objects from the Office Object Model.

Thoughts?

Comment: So, I never did figure it out, but I replaced the controls with others that don't have the same restriction.  We wanted to deprecate those particular controls anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for others with this issue (as you've solved it). We always create a UserControl that we set to fill the task pane. We then put all controls in the UserControl.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem.  I was putting a UserControl on the taskpane too.  The problem is that the third party controls were looking for a _Form_ specifically, which a UserControl is not.  I guess that's just poor coding on the part of the third party controls.

Comment: Ow - yes. Never require that unless the 3rd party control can only perform that operation on a Form.